# Adding quit command in python

Tags: exit

import random

def main():

```
    Interger_list = []
    guessTry = 0
    print('Hello!')
    print('Want to play guess my interger?')
    print('My interger is between -10 and 10')
    interger = random.randint(-10, 10)
       while True:
          print('Take a guess. ')
          guess = input()
          Interger_list.append(guess)
          guess = int(guess)
          guessTry = guessTry + 1
          if guess < interger:
              print('too low')  
          if guess > interger:
              print('too high')  
          if guess == interger:
              print('Winner')
              guessTry = str(guessTry)
              print('You guessed my interger in ' + guessTry + ' guesses!')
          for guess in Interger_list:
              print(guess)
```

main()

### i'm trying to add a quit command but have been hitting a wall.

if guess == q

```
break
```

### I keep getting error.

Comment: Would you mind writing few sentences ? And format your code ?

Comment: Also, what language is this? It looks like Python. And where are you trying to 'quit'?

Comment: it is python.  I want an infinite loop with the option to quit whenever the player decides.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare to the string q, so you should do

```
if guess == 'q':
     break
```

after your guess = input()

Comment: thank you, I guess i just kept putting it in the wrong spot